# Is there any drawback of using long instead of int when preparing a statement in java?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement, primitive

If I use `PreparedStatement.setLong` for a parameter whose corresponding db column is really a MySql `integer`, passing an `int` will obviously see it widened automatically in java. But in the "lower" levels of jdbc, does it matter in any way? Is it fine to use `long` to avoid extra work if I expect the datatype of the db column to change to `biginteger` in relatively near future?

**EDIT:** I do mean that the method setting the `long` always receives an `int`, so I won't accidentally be passing a value that's too large for the db column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When looking from a 100% formal perspective, it is possibly unsafe to use `setLong` for an `INTEGER` column. The JDBC 4.3 specification says that the `setXXX`-methods (with exception of `setObject`) follow the mappings of appendix B.2, which says a Java `long` maps to a SQL `BIGINT`. It then depends on whether the driver or database can use a `BIGINT` value with an `INTEGER` column.

The JDBC 1.20 specification on this matter says:

> #### 7.2.1 Data type conformance on IN parameters
>
> The PreparedStatement.setXXX methods do not perform any general data
>   type conversions. Instead the Java value is simply mapped to the
>   corresponding SQL type (following the mapping specified in Table 3 on
>   page 28) and that value is sent to the database.
>
> It is the programmer’s responsibility to make sure that the java type
>   of each argument maps to a SQL type that is compatible with the SQL
>   data type expected by the database. For maximum portability
>   programmers, should use Java types that correspond to the exact SQL
>   types expected by the database.
>
> If programmers require data type conversions for IN parameters, they
>   may use the PreparedStatement.setObject method which converts a Java
>   Object to a specified SQL type before sending the value to the
>   database.

This wording is no longer present in recent JDBC specifications, but its intent still applies and is defined by appendix B.2 in JDBC 4.3.

However, in practice, a lot of JDBC drivers - including MySQL Connector/J - support a wider range of conversions, similar to the one defined for `setObject` in appendix B.5, although each driver has its caveats and quirks here. For `Long` this means `getObject` can target `TINYINT`, `SMALLINT`, `INTEGER`, `BIGINT`, `REAL`, `FLOAT`, `DOUBLE`, `DECIMAL`, `NUMERIC`, `BIT`, `BOOLEAN`, `CHAR`, `VARCHAR`, `LONGVARCHAR`, and that - usually - means you can do the same with `setLong` as well.

This also provides uniformity with conversions for `getLong` defined in appendix B.6.

Whether or not it has any drawbacks, depends on the implementation. The MySQL Connector/J driver is open-source, so if you want to know the nitty-gritty details: look at the source.

However if your application actually uses a `long`, why is the database type `INTEGER`? Either use `BIGINT` in your database to match your application, or use `int` in your application to match the database.